# How to change using elasticsearch 5.5-alpine to elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4?

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, docker-compose

I am using elasticsearch5.5-alpine but I want to upgrade it to elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4 . Whenever I upgrade from docker-compose file I get elasticsearch unreachable error and also elasticsearch does not work on localhost:9200.
How can I solve this issue?

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
      - 8888:80
    depends_on:
      - web
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask
    ports:
        - 5000:5000
    volumes:
        - .:/code
    depends_on:
          - logstash

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash-oss:6.2.4
    volumes:
      - ./logstash-simple.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    expose:
      - 5140/udp    
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.5-alpine
    environment:
      - cluster.name=docker-clusters
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=false
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
      - "9200:9200"
      - "5044:5044"
```

Comment: Could you share the error message you are getting?

Comment: This is what I got after changing image to elasticsearch-oss:6.2.4:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2ytgQd9jJM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove this line:

```
- xpack.security.enabled=false
```

And then you need to fix the [bootstrap checks](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html):

```
elasticsearch_1  | ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
elasticsearch_1  | [1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]
```

[The guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/max-size-virtual-memory-check.html) tells you how to fix it:

> Elasticsearch and Lucene use `mmap` to great effect to map portions of
>   an index into the Elasticsearch address space. This keeps certain
>   index data off the JVM heap but in memory for blazing fast access. For
>   this to be effective, the Elasticsearch should have unlimited address
>   space. The maximum size virtual memory check enforces that the
>   Elasticsearch process has unlimited address space and is enforced only
>   on Linux. To pass the maximum size virtual memory check, you must
>   configure your system to allow the Elasticsearch process the ability
>   to have unlimited address space. This can be done via
>   `/etc/security/limits.conf` using the as setting to `unlimited` (note that
>   you might have to increase the limits for the `root` user too).

This command might help as well to fix the problem described above.

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Comment: Didn't work.
This is what I got after removing it: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G8WW9VgS9T/

Comment: Added more content

Comment: Thank you sir.
For linux users I have used this code to update the count:
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144